About automatically deleting data in mongodb
I am adding some data into mongodb. However, the data is automatically deleted after a certain period of time. I do not want this data to be lost or deleted
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { mongoURI, databaseName } = require('./config'); // Bağlantı bilgilerini al
const Keyword = require('./schema'); // Şema modelini al

// MongoDB bağlantısı
mongoose.connect(`${mongoURI}/${databaseName}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log(`Connected to database: ${databaseName}`);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Database connection error:', err);
    process.exit(1); // Hata durumunda işlemi sonlandır
});

// Yeni bir keyword ekleme
const newKeywordName = "example_keywordxxx";
const newKeywordData = {
    keyword_name: newKeywordName,
    keyword_process_server: "server_1",
};

// Direkt kod içinde kontrol ve ekleme
Keyword.exists({ keyword_name: newKeywordName })
    .then((exists) => {
        if (exists) {
            console.log(`Keyword "${newKeywordName}" already exists.`);
        } else {
            const newKeyword = new Keyword(newKeywordData);
            return newKeyword.save()
                .then(() => console.log('Keyword saved successfully'));
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Closing the database connection...');
        return mongoose.disconnect(); // İşlem tamamlandığında bağlantıyı kes
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error:', err);
        mongoose.disconnect(); // Hata durumunda bağlantıyı kes
    })
    .finally(() => {
        console.log('Process finished.');
        process.exit(0); // İşlemi tamamen sonlandır
    });


// schema.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const keywordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    keyword_name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, index: true }, // keyword_name benzersiz, zorunlu ve indeksli
    keyword_process_server: { type: String, required: true, default: "default_server" },
    keyword_is_available: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    keyword_is_success: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    keyword_add_time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    keyword_finish_time: { type: Date, default: null },
});

// Modeli dışa aktar
module.exports = mongoose.model('Keyword', keywordSchema);


The data in the mongodb compass installed on my Windows server is automatically deleted. I have not set a TTL value.

Problem Solved
Because I didn't set a password to the database, third parties removed my data. And they also want me to pay a ransom to get the data back.
